# Does bjam's cxxflags option remove trailing minus signs?

Tags: visual-c++, boost, boost-build, bjam

I'm trying to pass a Visual-C++ compiler option `/Zc:wchar_t-` (note trailing minus to switch it off) to bjam, boost's build tool like so:

```
bjam --build-type=complete runtime-link=shared variant=debug toolset=msvc-8.0 cxxflags="/Zc:wchar_t-" threading=multi debug-symbols=on debug-store=database --with-program_options stage
```

However, when I check the *.rsp file that contains the resulting compiler options (at `...\boost_1_44_0\bin.v2\libs\program_options\build\msvc-8.0\debug\debug-store-database\threading-multi\options_description.obj.rsp`), it will always contain `/Zc:wchar_t` as option, regardless whether I specify with `-` or without.

Is there something with the `cxxflags` that removes a trailing minus from the passed option?

<sub>**Note** that `/Zc:` is already set in `tools\build\v2\tools\msvc.jam`, resulting in the option being provided twice in the RSP file when I specify it with cxxflags -- still the one with cxxflags always gets its trailing minus removed, while -- if I edit msvc.jam -- the one in msvc.jam is taken verbatim and the minus preserved.</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is: Yes, bjam messes this up.

One can hack the `.jam` files to provide this option manually and it then works. (And yes, I'd provide where exactly, but I've since lost that test environment.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround i used. Add space to avoid removal of trailing -

```
cxxflags="/Zc:wchar_t- "
```